# Restore binary data with numpy fromfile that has been saved with numpy save

Tags: python, numpy, binaryfiles

I have a huge 3D-array (float16) that was stored to disk using `numpy.save`. When I load it, it floods my memory, so I need to read it in chunks and process the data step by step. But it seems that the data is read in a different order of dimensions than it had been saved. I prepared the following simple example:

```
import numpy as np

myArray = np.zeros((2, 5, 3))
content = np.arange(0,10).reshape((2, 5))
myArray[:,:,0] = content
myArray[:,:,1] = content*10
myArray[:,:,2] = content*100

np.save("myArray.npy", myArray.astype(np.float16))
```

`myArray` is a 3D array with 2 rows, 5 columns and 3 slices in the z-direction. Note that along `z` I have numbers from 0 to 9 in the first slice, then 0 to 90 in the second and 0 to 900 in the 3rd. Loading the first slice via `np.load` works just fine, but when I try the following, the order is messed up:

```
with open("myArray.npy", mode="rb") as fhandle:
    chunknp = np.fromfile(fhandle, count=10, dtype=np.float16)
    chunknp = np.resize(chunknp, new_shape=(2, 5, 1))

print(chunknp)
# Out: 
>> [[[2.630e+01]
  [2.133e+01]
  [1.700e+02]
  [5.960e-08]
  [7.033e-06]]

 [[2.922e-02]
  [1.380e+03]
  [9.535e+02]
  [2.908e-02]
  [8.255e-03]]]
```

`Count=10` gives me the first 10 elements which I thought were the 2x5 of z==0. Resizing to (2, 5, 1) is not essential to the problem, but that's the final order I need. 
How do I extract this correctly?

Comment: `save` writes an initial information buffer, then a copy of the data.

Comment: I know that it writes a header, but I thought that `np.fromfile` would read it and skip to the data at once?

Comment: No, fromfile does not distinguish that header.  You have to skip yourself.

Comment: How do I find out about its size?

Comment: Checkout [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/lib/format.py), that is the NPY file documentation

Comment: Thanks, anki, I realize it's multiples of 64. If I go `fhandle.seek(128)` I get: [  0.   0.   0.   1.  10. 100.   2.  20. 200.   3.] which is the correct data but in different order (it's [0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,2], [0,1,0], ... instead of [0,0,0], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [1,1,0], [0,2,0] ...)

Comment: If you look at the documentation and the entry of ```read_array```, you can see that depending on the order, you have to inverse the shape and the content.

Comment: So I guess I'll have to save the content again, moving axis=2 to position 0 if I do not want to skip wildly in the file to get my data in the order I want. That's tough, but it's manageable. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at `mmap_mode`?

Comment: @hpaulj: Yes, I have. It gives the same results because apparently I did not understand how a numpy object is written to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [103]: myArray = np.zeros((2, 5, 3)) 
     ...: content = np.arange(0,10).reshape((2, 5)) 
     ...: myArray[:,:,0] = content 
     ...: myArray[:,:,1] = content*10 
     ...: myArray[:,:,2] = content*100 
     ...:                                                                                                 
In [104]: myArray                                                                                         
Out[104]: 
array([[[  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  1.,  10., 100.],
        [  2.,  20., 200.],
        [  3.,  30., 300.],
        [  4.,  40., 400.]],

       [[  5.,  50., 500.],
        [  6.,  60., 600.],
        [  7.,  70., 700.],
        [  8.,  80., 800.],
        [  9.,  90., 900.]]])
In [105]: myArray.ravel()                                                                                 
Out[105]: 
array([  0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,  10., 100.,   2.,  20., 200.,   3.,  30.,
       300.,   4.,  40., 400.,   5.,  50., 500.,   6.,  60., 600.,   7.,
        70., 700.,   8.,  80., 800.,   9.,  90., 900.])
```

Using `tostring` shows the same order:

```
In [108]: np.frombuffer(myArray.tostring(), dtype=float)                                                  
Out[108]: 
array([  0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,  10., 100.,   2.,  20., 200.,   3.,  30.,
       300.,   4.,  40., 400.,   5.,  50., 500.,   6.,  60., 600.,   7.,
        70., 700.,   8.,  80., 800.,   9.,  90., 900.])
```

To select a consecutive slice of the stored data, index on the first dimension:

```
In [112]: myArray[0,:,:]                                                                                  
Out[112]: 
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  1.,  10., 100.],
       [  2.,  20., 200.],
       [  3.,  30., 300.],
       [  4.,  40., 400.]])
```

Indexing on the last access the `content` values, but that's not how they are stored in the `myArray` databuffer:

```
In [113]: myArray[:,:,0]                                                                                  
Out[113]: 
array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [5., 6., 7., 8., 9.]])
```

Comment: I have re-calculated my arrays via np.moveaxis(myArray, 2, 0) to bring back the third dimension to the front. This way, I can easily slice upon reading the data from file. Thank you for pointing this out!